# How to auto-select a photo radio button?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I'm trying to do a Greasemonkey script to auto-select a radio button. The poll has two images and when you click on one image, the option is selected and the *CAPTCHA* box is enabled to vote.

I'd like to know if there's any way to auto-select the image I want. I've tried some commands like `.click()` and `.checked` without success.

Here is the (partial) source HTML from the poll:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Validação de voto</legend>
<div class="box-votacao">
    <ul class="duplo-lateral clearFix" id="participantes">

        <li class="off">
            <div class="foto">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="foto-chamada" src="http://s.glbimg.com/et/bb/f/original/participantes/joao_carvalho_360x300.png" alt="João Carvalho">
                    <div class="selecionado"></div>
                    <p class="bloco-01 off">
                        <input name="opt" id="opt" value="1" type="radio">
                        <strong class="nome">João Carvalho</strong>
                    </p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <p class="legenda">Para votar em João Carvalho, disque 0303 108 8401 ou envie um SMS para 88401</p>
        </li>
        <li class="off ultimo">
            <div class="foto">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="foto-chamada" src="http://s.glbimg.com/et/bb/f/original/participantes/yuri_360x300.png" alt="Yuri">
                    <div class="selecionado"></div>
                    <p class="bloco-01 off">
                        <input name="opt" id="opt" value="2" type="radio">
                        <strong class="nome">Yuri</strong>
                    </p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <p class="legenda">Para votar em Yuri, disque 0303 108 8402 ou envie um SMS para 88402</p>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
<div class="validacao clearFix noBorder">
    <div id="desabilitado"></div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img id="captcha" title="seguranca" />
        </li>
        <li class="digitar-codigo">
            <input name="answer" type="text" />
            <p id="erro" class="erro"><span>Erro!</span> <span class="erro-txt">Texto incorreto. Tente novamente.</span></p>
        </li>
        <li class="botao">
            <span><input name="votar" type="submit" class="submit" value="votar"/></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does your script determine which image to click?

And it ***is*** the image that's clicked?  Assuming that is true, then something like this should work:

```
var targImage   = document.querySelector ("div.box-votacao img.foto-chamada[alt='João Carvalho']");
var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
targImage.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
```

If it doesn't work, post a link to the target page, if it's public... or a link to a saved snapshot of the page -- including javascript -- if it's not public.

---

---

**Update**, now that [the target page](http://tvg.globo.com/bbb/bbb12/votacao/291.html) has been given.

That page is a little tricky; a little more than just a click is required.  Also, examining the page, it is not the image that gets clicked it is click handlers on the containing `<li>` that matter.

So, with a combination of clicking and some JS, the following has been tested to work:

```
//--- Click the link and list-item associated with the desired image.
var targImg     = document.querySelector ("div.box-votacao img.foto-chamada[alt='João Carvalho']");
targLink        = targImg.parentNode;
targListItem    = targImg.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;

clickNode (targListItem);

var ps          = unsafeWindow.ps;
for (var j in ps) {
    if (ps[j].className) {
        ps[j].className = ps[j].className.replace ("on", "off");
    }
}
targListItem.className  = targListItem.className.replace ("off", "on");
targListItem.getElementsByTagName ("input")[0].checked = "true";

var captchaBox  = document.querySelector ("#desabilitado");
if (captchaBox) {
    captchaBox.id = "habilitado";
}


function clickNode (targNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    targNode.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

Finally, this page may have been designed to thwart scripting like Greasemonkey.  If so, your script may be against the terms of service (not reading much Portuguese, I didn't go looking for them) and they may take countermeasures to bust this script.

Comment: Last code I've tryied:

`code`
var name = document.getElementsByClassName('foto-chamada');
name[i].click();
`code`

I'd change [i] depending of the one I'd to vote


I've tryied your code and didn't worked. Here it's the link http://tvg.globo.com/bbb/bbb12/votacao/291.html

Comment: The poll will go off today, if it's off before you could see, here it's the snapshots. once the page is loaded http://i43.tinypic.com/29kq82o.png once the option is selected http://i40.tinypic.com/5n4okm.png code from the page pastebin.com/raw.php?i=98V7eMA6 thx in advance

Comment: After examining that page and its code, I've updated the answer. The page design suggests rudimentary anti-scripting measures *might* have been built in. Just to be sure, don't use this code to violate any laws or terms of service that may apply.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. The poll has already expired, I'll test when a new one appears. I know the site has this kind of protection to avoid robots and macros, but my intention was have a example instead of spread the code to violate anything. Because there's another site I believe has a similar kind of polls, like this one http://televisao.uol.com.br/bbb/bbb12/enquetes/2012/02/02/quem-merece-vencer-o-bbb12.htm 
In this case there's no captcha, but the selection looks similar. click() doesn't work too. Assuming I'm right I'll try to make a code for this one based on yours.

Comment: Just tested it and worked, thank you again. I added this document.getElementsByName('answer')[0].focus();